# Remove bold formatting on Dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a dataframe as below, with date as Index

```
Date           Count
01/01/2020       10
02/01/2020       14
03/01/2020        7
```

When writing the dataframe to excel, the index is always in bold. how do I remove the bold formatting on the index?

Comment: What do you mean by "removing the bold formatting"? It isn't obvious to me what you mean.

Comment: I mean when it's written to an excel file, the index in a dataframe is always bold. I'm wondering if it's possible to have it without the bold formatting

Comment: How working `df.reset_index().to_excel(file, index=False)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use trick - convert index to column and then not write index to file like:

```
df.reset_index().to_excel(file, index=False)
```